# ListView inside ViewPager with setRotationY transformer not working

Tags: android, listview, transformation

I'm creating a ViewPager with a ListView on each page on Android. The ViewPager scrolls horizontally and the ListViews scroll vertically. Both the ViewPager and the ListViews work as expected even with custom PageTransformers on the ViewPager.

Until, the `setRotationY` is used in the transformer. Then the ViewPager still works, but the ListView doesn't react to vertical scrolling anymore.

The transformer I'm using is this one: [CubeOutTransformer](https://github.com/geftimov/android-viewpager-transformers/wiki/CubeOutTransformer).

If I try the [AccordionTransformer](https://github.com/geftimov/android-viewpager-transformers/wiki/AccordionTransformer) (which doesn't use `setRotationY`), it works again.

Any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: ListView doesn't support nested scrolling. Switch to RecyclerView instead.

Comment: Could you link to sources of any kind? In contradiction to your comment my question clearly says that the setup actually works. Until, I use the `setRotationY` transformation on the ViewPager.

Also it's the ViewPager that is nesting. The ListViews are the children here, while the ViewPager is the parent.